# Two nagios instances in the same machine

Tags: centos, redhat, monitoring, nagios, nrpe

After days of surfing on the net and trying by myself, I urgently need your help.
So, I have Nagios Core 4.4.3 installed in my centos machine that I use to monitor **PROD and TEST** environnement of one of our system.
I want to **seperate** these two environnements by having one instance of nagios that monitor PROD and another one that monitor Test(which is more logic).
How Can I do that please ?
Thanks for help

Comment: What is the reasoning behind wanting 2 instances of Nagios instead of just using different hostgroups?

Comment: I want to totally  seperate the two environnements.My goal is having one link for PROD monitoring displayed on a screen and other link for TEST monitoring displayed on other screen.

Comment: Your goal does not require you to have two entirely separate installations of Nagios core. How are you planning on displaying them?

Answer (score 0):

you have to migrate the configuration files to the new server.

1)  Install new Nagios server

2)  Migrate existing corresponding configuration files to the new server (*.cfg files)

3)  Verify the configuration

4)  Start Ngaios server

From client side change the allowed host to new server